# Pandas df - unnest 1 column that has nested dictionaries, but only unnest the key not the values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following column cPeriod that has multiple rows that look like this:

```
{'firstDate': {'year': 2022, 'month': 10, 'day': 16}, 'lastDate': {'year': 2022, 'month': 11, 'day': 12}}
```

I want to only split out the cPeriod by 2 columns so the new columns would be `cperiod.firstdate` and `cperiod.lastdate`.

I've tried this but it just unnests too much!

```
df = df.join(json_normalize(df["cPeriod"].tolist()).add_prefix("cPeriod.")).drop(["cPeriod"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah this worked for me! It created 2 columns, firstdate and lastdate, I have to just rename them to have the cperiod. prefix:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('cPeriod').values.tolist()))
```